# Add a hotkey to plugin command for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I created a plugin which adds a h1 formatting to a given text. Therefore I added the command to the toolbar which works perfect.
Now I try to bind my new command "heading-h1-cmd" to a shortcut:

```
config.keystrokes = [[ CKEDITOR.ALT + 77, 'heading-h1-cmd' ]];
```

Why is my command not triggered?
Other shortcuts like 'bold' work like they should.

Comment: @oleq's answer mentions an alternative way of setting keystrokes, but [`config.keystrokes`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-keystrokes) exists as well. You might forgot about clearing your cache - otherwise I see no reason why it wouldn't work. (Edit: actually, you can also try to set the `config.keystrokes` on the fly, while it will only work before editor creation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [`editor.setKeystroke()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke), it's available since v4.0:

```
editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 77, 'heading-h1-cmd' );
```